# reassembled the matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am new user of matlab. My question is that 
I make a matrix, by using this command

```
for i =1:n
    perm(:,i)=emp(:,i); % (where emp is already calculated)
end
```

then I want to make a matrix

```
A(i,i)=B(perm(:,i),perm(:,i));
```

that is for i=1 it evaluate the matrix B using first column for i=2 it uses 2nd row and so on. (the perms are the nodes of my problem)

Answer (score 0):

Your first loop just copies emp to perm. It is faster to just copy emp to perm i.e.

```
perm=emp;
```

Your question regarding A(i,i) is a little confusing. A(i,i) are the diagonals of the matrix A. B(perm(:,i),perm(:,i)) returns a matrix, thus A(i,i)=B(perm(:,i),perm(:,i)) produces and error. You should clarify a little bit more what you want to do.

Comment: I want to extract the matricess from the matrix B on the nodes I defined by perm(:,i) which are the ith coloumn matrix of emp and I want to calculate A1= B(perm(:,1),perm(:,1)), A2=B(perm(:,2),perm(:,2)) that is make a loop such that for i =1:n I got A1, A2 and so on

Comment: I still can't follow what you want to do. Be more specific and provide details in human readable form!