# Reassemble matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I want to extract the matrices from the matrix B on the nodes I defined by `perm(:,i)` which are the ith column matrix of `emp` and I want to calculate `A1= B(perm(:,1),perm(:,1))`, `A2=B(perm(:,2),perm(:,2))` that is make a loop such that:

```
for i=1:n
    I got A1, A2 and so on –
```

Comment: How should I extract this and make loop, because when I A(i)=B(perm(:,i),perm(:,i)) then it gives me error.

Comment: This question looks very similar to your other question [reassembled the matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740898/reassembled-the-matrix), posting duplicate questions is not a good way to get an answer (unless I misunderstood, in which case you can disregard my comment). More to the point, you should try to explain in as much details as reasonable what your problem is (for example how you obtain `B` and `perm` matrices) and what your context is so that other people can understand your question and help you.

Comment: spy(K.A)
  perm=[fem.intnodes; fem.snodes];
 spy(K.A(perm,perm))
 spy(K.A(perm(1:49),perm(1:49)))
 j=2;
    perm1=fem.intnodes(fem.intnodesinfo(j)+1:sum(fem.intnodesinfo(j:j+1)));
   A2=K.A(perm1,perm1);
j=1;
    perm2 =fem.intnodes(fem.intnodesinfo(j)+1:sum(fem.intnodesinfo(j:j+1)));

A1=K.A(perm2,perm2);
If I do in this way then each time I have to calculate perm1, perm2 and so on and A1, A2 and so on,. but I want to calculate perm(i) and by using i=1:n I could get A(i), so that I dont need to calculate each time seperately, I dont know Could I explain properly or not.

Comment: Actually I am new user of stack and matalb I dont know how to use it properly, I am sorry for any thing rubbish pot=sted by me.

Comment: @user1131808: I recommend you edit your question with the above comments you made to make it more clear. As you can see, reading code inside a comment is very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

From what i can discern, it seems that you want to dynamically extract a sub-matrix from matrix B, according to the perms matrix. Your problem, it seems, is that you cannot do this in a loop, because you don't know how to dynamically create matrices. Your solution is to create a cell and input each sub-matrix in the cell. Thus, if A is your cell then,

```
A=cell(1,N);

for i=1:N
  A{i}=B(perm(:,i),perm(:,i));
end
```

You can get the matrix Ai from the cell using,

```
Ai=A{i};  %notice the curly braces {}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want variables named A1, A2, &c, you can use `eval`:

```
for i = 1:N
  eval(['A' num2str(i) ' = B(perm(:,i),perm(:,i))']);
end
```

However, it's probably not a good idea and you'd better use cells as shown by @Jorge. Cells can contain anything and are much more convenient.